# Angular 4 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: angular, http, authentication, jwt

This is a basic `Angular 4` application with `Django Rest framework` as backend .I am using `JWT` token for authentication.When I click the login button, this error shows. I couldn't find why is this happening. I am new to `Typescript` and `Angular 4`, Hope someone can solve this problem.I have tried to change  `signInComponent.html` but problem didn't solve

[image]

[image]

** SignInComponent.ts**

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms/src/directives';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-sign-in',
templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent {
token=null ;  
formError: string;
submitting = false;

constructor(private router:Router, private authService:UserService) { }

onSubmit(signInForm: NgForm ) {

if (signInForm.valid) {

  console.log('submitting...', signInForm);
  this.submitting = true;
  this.formError = null;

  this.authService.login(signInForm.value.username, 
signInForm.value.password)
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.token=data['data'];
        console.log( this.token['token'])
        this.authService.saveJWT(this.token['token']);
        this.authService.isAuthenticated =true;
        this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
      },
      (err)=> {
        this.submitting = false;
        console.log('got error: ', err);
        this.formError = err;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    );

}
 this.authService.ping().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('got token yeeh: ');
  console.log(this.authService.getJwt());
  },
  );

} 
}
```

** SignInComponent.html**

```
<div class="sign-in-form">
<img src="./assets/logo.jpg" width="320" />
<h4>Sign In</h4>
<form #signInForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(signInForm)" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" name="username" required placeholder="User Name" 
ngModel #username="ngModel" />
<div [hidden]="username.valid || username.pristine" class="alert alert-
danger">
User Name is required.
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" name="password" required type="password"  
placeholder="Password" ngModel #password="ngModel"/>
  <div [hidden]="password.valid || password.pristine" class="alert alert-
danger">
    Password is required.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" ngModel /> Remember Me
  </label>
</div>
<div *ngIf="formError" class="alert alert-danger">
  {{ formError }}
</div>
<div *ngIf="!submitting">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="submitting">
  <p class="message">Signing In...</p>
</div>

</form>
</div>
```

** AuthService.ts**

```
import { any } from 'codelyzer/util/function';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService  {


 isAuthenticated = false;

 constructor(private router: Router ,private http:HttpClient  ) { 

 }

 saveJWT(strToken: string): any {
 localStorage.setItem('JWT',strToken);
 }

 login(username: string, password: string):Observable<any> {

 let headers =new HttpHeaders();
 var body = "username="+username+"&password="+password;
 headers = headers.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 return  this.http.post('http://nucore.ddns.net:800/v1/user/login', body, {
   headers:headers});
 }
 getJwt():string
{

 return localStorage.getItem('JWT');

}
ping():Observable<any> {
return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')

}

logOut() {
// remove user from local storage to log user out
localStorage.removeItem('JWT');
this.isAuthenticated = false;
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}



}
```

**Network Screenshot**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: where are you reading that length property

Comment: @RahulSingh as 'got error: ' is logged in the console i think it is going in the error callback of subscribe function. Basim can u pls post a screenshot of network tab with the login call in detail view ?

Comment: @Dhyey I added screenshot

Comment: @BasimE-Darussalam this isn't the login call. This is just a webpack call it uses internally for live reloading and other stuff. Can u pls click on the login button which calls `authService.login` method and then post the screenshot

Comment: @Dhyey is that you wanted?

Comment: @BasimE-Darussalam of the network tab at this point.

Comment: @Dhyey that just blank no request going

Answer (score 4):

Posting this as an answer because I just spent an entire day trying to figure this out while migrating from Angular 2 to Angular 6, and I'm sure someone has the same error.

The problem was that the http interceptor added the auth token to the login request, at which point the auth token is null. So make sure that the authinterceptor doesn't try to add the token to the login request

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for 6+ hours. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {


  isAuthenticated = false;

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) {

  }

  saveJWT(strToken: string): any {
    localStorage.setItem('JWT', strToken);
  }

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {

    const head = new Headers();
    const body = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
    head.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post('http://nucore.ddns.net:800/v1/user/login', body, {
      headers: head
    });
  }

  getJwt(): string {

    return localStorage.getItem('JWT');

  }

  ping(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')

  }

  logOut() {
// remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('JWT');
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }


}
```

Comment: Have a try?  at userService

Comment: I am using HttpClient so I think this will not work instead of import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http I used {HttpClientModule} from 
 '@angular/common/http

Comment: your code is running right here. There is no ‘length' problem

Comment: yup , This project was running well, but  suddenly I got these error without changing anything in the code

Comment: @BasimE-Darussalam sorry to resurrect the old thread, but I'm facing the very same issue. Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: @mutantkeyboard is your interceptor adding the auth token on the login request itself?

Comment: @Joakim I managed to sort it out in the end. The problem in my case was NGRX, and the way that I was dispatching the login state. Login itself works without problems, but thank you for coming back. I appreciate it.